# acess session in view (javascript) from the controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my controller code. I want to get values stored in session in view(javascript code)

```
      decimal.TryParse(permotion.PROMOTION_AMOUNT.ToString(), out promotionAmount);
      int.TryParse(permotion.PROMOTION_TYPE_ID.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                                    out promotionTypeId);
      Session["PromotionAmount"] = promotionAmount;
      Session["TypeId"] = promotionTypeId;
```

view code is:

```
     var amount='@Session["PromotionAmount"]';
     var id='@Session["TypeId"]';
     alert(amount)
     alert(id)
```

but this java-script code is returning empty string. How I can retrieve session value in view? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure the session keys have a value?

Comment: yes, I have debug it,these session keys have values

Comment: Does the script happen to be in a separate `.js` file (in which case it wont work)?

Answer (score 2):

You can put the values within a ViewModel / ViewData

```
ViewData["hdnFieldValue"] = "some value";
```

use a hidden string to store in the HTML

```
@Html.Hidden("hdnField", ViewData["hdnFieldValue"], new {@id = "hdnField"})
```

Then when document is loaded retrieve via JS

```
var myValue = document.GetElementById(hdnFieldValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

No issue with that code. It will work fine. Which i am using in my page. Use `Convert.ToString(Session["value"])`. Even if its not working, check weather Session has value or not.